# Change other div on hover

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/duo6foe5/1/) 
**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="hover">
            <div class="imgdiv"></div>
       </div>
    </a>
    <div class="imgdiv_2">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
a{
    height:250px;width:250px;
}
.hover{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
.hover:hover > .imgdiv{
    opacity:0.5;
    height:300px;
}
.hover:

hover + .imgdiv_2{
    width:4300px;
}
.imgdiv{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0;
}
.imgdiv_2{
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.1;
}
```

I have a problem with this part:

```
hover + .imgdiv_2{
    width:4300px;
}
```

How can I change .imgdiv_2 when I hover .hover
Is this even possible in CSS only?
I can not change the HTML structure or the 250px width.
Is there a way I can select the entire css path from the body?

Comment: It's not possible in CSS alone. Also, `block` elements should not descend your `inline` elements.

Comment: @George Why isn't it possible? Is it because it's nested too much, is it possible if there wasn't a <a>?

Comment: Exactly, there is no parent selector in CSS, hence no way to select 'up' the DOM tree. If there wasn't an anchor then yes, [it would work](http://jsfiddle.net/duo6foe5/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because CSS selectors can target only an element's descendants or followed siblings... That's how CSS works.

But on your scenario, since the `a` tag is a sibling to the `.imgdiv_2`, you can set the `:hover` on it:

```
a:hover + .imgdiv_2{
    width:4300px;
}
```

Maybe narrowing it by adding a class to the `a` tag...

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/duo6foe5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sibling selector, two elements must be siblings :)

I edited your html:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="hover">
        <div class="imgdiv"></div>
   </div>

<div class="imgdiv_2">

</div>
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duo6foe5/2/)

Comment: The question states *I can not change the HTML structure*

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Missed that.